# Deserialize Json to C# object with array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Hello I have serious issues with populating my JSON file to C# object, because JSON contains "array of arrays of arrays". I need to create class with all the arrays to be able load the files there after deserialize, but i have no idea how to create structure like that.

JSON file:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "UserID": "1001",
            "web_id": "2753",
            "certificate_id": "31",
            "domain": "testsomething.com",
            "status": "ssl_uninstalling",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-15 15:08:04",
            "IP": "xx.x.xxx.xxx",
            "OS_version": "CentOS release 4.8"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "UserID": "1001",
            "web_id": "2753",
            "certificate_id": "31",
            "domain": "admin.testsomething.com",
            "status": "ssl_uninstalling",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-13 14:19:45",
            "IP": "xx.x.xxx.xxx",
            "OS_version": "CentOS release 4.8"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "UserID": "1001",
            "web_id": "2753",
            "certificate_id": "31",
            "domain": "www.testsomething16.com",
            "status": "ssl_uninstalling",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-16 16:22:40",
            "IP": "xx.x.xxx.xxx",
            "OS_version": "CentOS release 4.8"
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "UserID": "1001",
            "web_id": "2753",
            "certificate_id": "31",
            "domain": "blog.testsomething.com",
            "status": "ssl_uninstalling",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-16 16:22:40",
            "IP": "xx.x.xxx.xxx",
            "OS_version": "CentOS release 4.8"
        }
    ],
    "errors": []
}
```

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: In Visual Studio it is just Copy'SpecialPaste Json as Class

Comment: Do you want to just have a tool do all the work (which is fine until there is a variation in the JSON, but will be OK if the JSON is consistent), or do you want code that you control the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure for your json might look like

```
public class Result
{

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UserID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("web_id")]
    public string web_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("certificate_id")]
    public string certificate_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string domain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public string updated_at { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IP")]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OS_version")]
    public string OS_version { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public bool status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
}
```

You can use Visual Studio to create classes for you out of JSON.
Copy your JSON in the clipboard. that means just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then go to Visual Studio Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes

Another way out to create class sturcture for your JSON could be you can go to [json2csharp: generate c# classes from json](http://json2csharp.com) and create the classes.

Comment: Thanks so much. Its such easy and I spend on it so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a model like below:

```
public class Example
    {
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public ResultModel ResultModel { get; set; }
        public bool Error { get; set; }

        public Example()
        {
            ResultModel = new ResultModel();
        }
    }

    public class ResultModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int WebId { get; set; }
    }
```