# C# WPF Custom JSON Converter for "Array of Object" to "Array of Arrays" to python server

Tags: c#, json

Good evening everyone.

I have a C# WPF application which needs to send JSON requests to a python server that is running completely separate from this program.  I have already established successful comms via a ListBox and an observable collection and a JsonSerializer as shown below:

```
try
{
    // PeekSignalsList is the ObservableCollection
    StringContent? jsonString = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PeekSignalsList, Formatting.Indented), 
        Encoding.UTF8, 
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    if (jsonString is not null)
    {
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("host", $"{ServerAddress}");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "python-requests/2.31.0");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "*/*");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("connection", "keep-alive");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-type", "application/json");

        // this works just fine
        var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"http://{ServerAddress}/peek_data"),
            Content = jsonString,
        };

        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else
    {
        PeekLog += $"ECI-PeekOneShot:\tJson serialization returned null{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

I have another ListView control which has two fields in it that are Bound to another ObservableCollection of type PokeSignal.  When I use the same approach as above I get the difference in what wireshark sees shown in the pictures below.  This is causing the server to reject my requests.

Below is the JSON data from wireshark of what the python test script sends to the python server

```
JSON raw form:
    [
        [
            "counter",
            11
        ]
    ]


Array
    Array
        [Path with value: /[]/[]:counter]
        [Member with value: []:counter]
        String value: counter
        [Path with value: /[]/[]:11]
        [Member with value: []:11]
        Number value: 11
```

And here is a the JSON data from wireshark of what my C# program is sending to the python server

```
JSON raw form:
    [
        {
            "SignalName": "counter",
            "SignalValue": 0
        }
    ]

Array
    Object
        Member: SignalName
            [Path with value: /[]/SignalName:counter]
            [Member with value: SignalName:counter]
            String value: counter
            Key: SignalName
            [Path: /[]/SignalName]
        Member: SignalValue
            [Path with value: /[]/SignalValue:0]
            [Member with value: SignalValue:0]
            Number value: 0
            Key: SignalValue
            [Path: /[]/SignalValue]
```

I know I need a custom Json Serializer and have made an attempt at creating one using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) and some other resources.  I have never done this before so I'm a little stuck with how to make the Json Converter create the "Array of Arrays" in the picture.

Here is my PokeSignal.cs

```
namespace EngineeringLabUi.Models
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PokeSignalJsonConverter))]
    public class PokeSignal
    {
        public PokeSignal(string? signalName, int? signalValue)
        {
            SignalName = signalName;
            SignalValue = signalValue;
        }

        public PokeSignal()
        {
            SignalName = string.Empty;
            SignalValue = 0;
        }

        // not sure what to do here
        public override string ToString() => $"{SignalName}:{SignalValue}";

        public static PokeSignal Parse(string input)
        {
            // not sure what to do here
            int value = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));
            string name = input;

            return new PokeSignal(name, value);
        }

        public string? SignalName { get; set; }
        public int? SignalValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And here is my converter which is modeled after the link above:

```
namespace EngineeringLabUi.Converters
{
    public class PokeSignalJsonConverter : JsonConverter<PokeSignal>
    {
        public override PokeSignal? ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                             Type objectType,
                                             PokeSignal? existingValue,
                                             bool hasExistingValue,
                                             Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return PokeSignal.Parse(reader.ToString()!);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                       PokeSignal? value,
                                       Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(value?.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Also modeled after the link above is the following code where I am trying to use the converter but am also getting an error:

```
try
{
    var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
        Converters =
        {
            /* Error:  cannot convert from 'EngineeringLabUi.Converters.PokeSignalJsonConverter' to 
             *  'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter'
             *
             * Error:  The best overloaded Add method 'ICollection<JsonConverter>.Add(JsonConverter)' 
             * for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments    
             */
            new PokeSignalJsonConverter()
        }
    };
    StringContent? jsonString = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PokeSignalsList, Formatting.Indented),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    if (jsonString is not null)
    {
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("host", $"{ServerAddress}");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "python-requests/2.31.0");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "*/*");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("connection", "keep-alive");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-type", "application/json");

        var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"http://{ServerAddress}/poke_data"),
            Content = jsonString,
        };

        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    else
    {
        PokeLog += $"ECI-PokeOneShot:\tJson serialization returned null{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

So I'm not sure if I'm even taking the right approach as I have seen that there are many different ways to create and use Json Converters.

Any help is much appreciated!

Some other Resources I have looked into.

[Ignore property with attribute in custom JSON converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469897/ignore-property-with-attribute-in-custom-json-converter)

[Deserialize Json to C# object with array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361638/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-object-with-array-of-arrays)

***** Edit *****
Thanks @dbc for providing details and clarification for me on this.

- Key Take Aways

  - Fundamental misunderstanding of the following

    - JSON serialization and deserialization

      - JSON converters
      - Creation
      - Implementation packages and supporting software differences
      - Usage
      - Decorations
      - Contracts

For those looking at this in the future here is my updated PokeSignal.cs:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<PokeSignal>))]
[DataContract]
public class PokeSignal(string? signalName, int? signalValue)
{
    public PokeSignal() : this(string.Empty, 0)
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public string? SignalName { get; set; } = signalName;

    [JsonProperty(Order = 12)]
    public int? SignalValue { get; set; } = signalValue;
}
```

My updated converter is taken directly from the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461518/how-to-deserialize-an-array-of-values-with-a-fixed-schema-to-a-strongly-typed-da/39462464#39462464) and I have given credit in my code to dbc.

In general when learning and researching this subject it is important to know the format of the JSON you need to create, which package provides the options to create that format, how to properly override the functions to produce that result, how to use function decorations to indicate that a converter is assigned to a class object, and how to use the converter.

Again, Thanks dbc!

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to replace the JSON screen shots with actual raw textual JSON samples?  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content in posts, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: *Error:  cannot convert from 'EngineeringLabUi.Converters.PokeSignalJsonConverter' to 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter'* -- you are mixing serializers.  Your `PokeSignalJsonConverter` uses `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` so it is written against Json.NET, but `JsonSerializerOptions` is for System.Text.Json, a totally different serializer that also happens to have a class named `JsonConverter`.  See e.g. [JsonConverter equivalent in using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56360401).  You need to use one serializer or the other consistently.

Comment: @dbc Thank you, Question updated as requested.  Also, this may be highly subjective as a question, but is one better to use than the other?  For the JSON string I'm trying to produce I mean.  I already have most of my code working and I just need to figure this particular thing out and would like to not have to change the way I've implemented the other functionality.

Comment: In general we need a [mcve] for the part of your code that isn't working, which I reckon would be the converter, model, and required JSON.  Did using either System.Text.Json or Json.NET consistently solve your problem?  If not, which serializer do you want to use?  If Json.NET, `ObjectToArrayConverter<PokeSignal>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182) to [How to deserialize an array of values with a fixed schema to a strongly typed data class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461518/3744182) might be what you need.

Comment: @dbc Thanks I think you are correct I will implement and test today.  To me terms are a little confusing.  Deserialize vs Serialize.  I had been thinking that Serializing was the act of taking something and converting into JSON and Deserializing was the opposite.

Comment: That is what "Serialize" and "Deserialize" mean.  But more often than not answers about serialization or deserialization cover both, so you can end up with a duplicate answer even if the question only mentioned one or the other.

Comment: @dbc Also to answer your other question I had used Newtonsoft to get my other functionality to work as I was just trying to convert a List<string> into JSON.  Not really having a preference but rather never having done it before as well as any JSON serialization in C# before.  A little in other languages such as python though.  Also, yes it is not hard to get a little mixed up when surfing through other answers on this subject.